# RemoveLiquidity from Uniswap fork remaining tokens in reserves

Tags: solidity

I am working on the Uniswap fork but the UI was developed by myself.

I am able to remove the Liquidity, e.g. if I have minted 100023 Lp tokens and remove this with the burn mechanism then some tokens like 0.00012 remain in the reserves. The problem is that I can not add new tokens because Uniswap calculates an optimal value from reserves() mean I can not add higher values than 0.00012. Can someone help how to remove all values from reserves?

```
 function removeLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) public override ensure(deadline) returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH) {
        (amountToken, amountETH) = removeLiquidity(
            token,
            WETH,
            liquidity,
            amountTokenMin,
            amountETHMin,
            address(this),
            deadline
        );
        TransferHelper.safeTransfer(token, to, amountToken);
        IWETH(WETH).withdraw(amountETH);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferETH(to, amountETH);
    }
```